# A group-like topological monoid is a loop space

Tags: algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

I am looking for an elementary reference for the following fact.

> Let $M$ be a topological monoid and suppose moreover that it is group-like, ie. $\pi_{0}(M)$ is a group. Then the canonical map $M \rightarrow \Omega BM$ is a weak equivalence.

I am also interested in the simplicial analogue of the above. I know this follows from group-completion, for example in the way it is stated in Goerss-Jardine, but this is supposed to be the trivial case and so I am looking for a simple argument.

Comment: This probably depends on your model for $BM$, but see, for example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704397/a-group-like-topological-monoid-is-a-loop-space

Comment: @Drew, this is a link to the very question, no..?

Comment: Opps, I have no idea how that happened. I think I meant to link to this: http://math.stanford.edu/~carym/bar.pdf

Answer (score 3):

See Proposition D.2 in Hatcher's [exposition of the Madsen-Weiss theorem.](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/MW.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Another reference is Rudyak, *On Thom Spectra, Orientability and Cobordism*, Corollary 1.68 (page 214). A full proof is given.